# Cannot enable email/password authentication provider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, chat

[image]

I am enabling email/password sign in method in firebase menu.The code for creating a new user and also to login are given below:

```
$scope.chatRef = new Firebase("https://project-497516355415797631.firebaseio.com");

$scope.login = function(){
    $scope.chatRef.authWithPassword({
      email    : "debojyoti1@gmail.com",
      password : "123456"
    }, function(error, authData) {
      if (error) {
        console.log("Login Failed!", error);
      } else {
        console.log("Authenticated successfully with payload:", authData);
      }
    });
}

$scope.createUser = function(){
    $scope.chatRef.createUser({
      email    : "bobtony@firebase.com",
      password : "correcthorsebatterystaple"
    }, function(error, userData) {
      if (error) {
        console.log("Error creating user:", error);
      } else {
        console.log("Successfully created user account with uid:", userData.uid);
      }
    });
}
```

Still the error `Error: The specified authentication provider is not enabled for this Firebase.` is showing.What i am doing wrong?Thank you for your time.

Comment: You are using the old SDK for your project. the "new Firebase("etc...")" is for the Firebase Legacy Version not the Firebase 3.0 version  you should use this documentation

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the old SDK for your project. the "new Firebase("etc...")" is for the Firebase Legacy Version not the Firebase 3.0 version you should use this documentation

https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup